# scala T is not a class

Tags: scala, generics, classtag

I have a method like:

```
  def loadConfiguration[T <: Product](implicit A: Configs[T]): T = {
```

and a class

```
trait SparkBaseRunner[T <: Product] extends App {
```

when calling the first method from within the `SparkBaseRunner` class like

```
ConfigurationUtils.loadConfiguration[T]
```

the compile error is:

```
T is not a class
```

What can I do to fix this generics related issue?

Comment: `T` is just a placeholder name, when you call the method you need to specify a concrete type

Comment: You mean I need to specify a concrete name of a class like `case class Foo()`, i.e. `Foo`?

Comment: Yes, any class that extends `Product` will do.  `T <: Product` means that whatever type you choose, it must extends `Product.  case classes and tuples all extend `Product` implicitly.

Comment: Is there no way I can simply specify a generic type i.e. `T` here? And have the concrete class be specified in the subclass of the trait `SparkBaseRunner[T <: Product]`.

Comment: You should be able to specify the type T actually, so I'm not sure where that error is coming from.  Do you have a complete example you could post?  The implicit Configs parameter to `loadConfiguration` could be a problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also have `implicit A: Configs[T]` available "when calling the first method from within the SparkBaseRunner class", and you don't. The error comes from the way this library tries to find one.

The easy way is to make it a constructor parameter, which requires changing from a trait to an abstract class:

```
abstract class SparkBaseRunner[T <: Product](implicit A: Configs[T]) extends App {

// in extending class (Bar is a case class or 
// some other type for which an implicit Configs[Bar] exists)
class Foo extends SparkBaseRunner[Bar] { ... }
```

If `SparkBaseRunner` needs to be a trait, you can add the implicit parameter to all methods which need it, or make it an abstract `val` and provide it manually in subclasses

Comment: Would you recommend an abstract class over a trait?

Comment: Given only this, yes, but it depends on your other requirements.

Comment: E.g. if you need it be mixed in to some other class which already has a superclass, it has to be a trait.